# How to change size of pagination icons in angular-slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

i have to reduce size of pagination icons and fonts in order to fit into a slickgrid
attached screenshot for ref-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuQPV.png)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the CSS style of the Pagination buttons is not going to help much, it will barely give you back couple of pixels, if you want to do that then I added a couple more SASS variables if you want to play with them

with SASS, you can lower these 2 variables (defaults are shown below, for more take a look at all the SASS [variables](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/styles/_variables.scss#L672))

```
$pagination-button-height:   32px;     // around 28px
$pagination-button-padding:  6px 12px; // around 4px 8px
```

Another thing you could maybe try is to change the English translation for "items per page" and remove the word "items" (via [Translations (Wiki)](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Localization) or [Locale File (Wiki)](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Localization-with-Custom-Locales) file depending on what you use).

```json
{
  "ITEMS_PER_PAGE": "items per page" // --> "per page"
}
```

The last option would be to create your own Custom Pagination but that would require much more effort but someone did just that and you can see it in this [Example - Custom Pagination](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/swt)

Comment: where to change "items per page" to "per page" i am using  "angular-slickgrid": "2.19.0",

Comment: via Translations or Locale file depending on what you use

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand. Which file exactly?